# Linux has about 50% usage on idle

Tags: linux, cpu, embedded, cpu-usage

I have an embedded machine running Linux Arch, and it is always on 50% usage (4 cores 800mhz) running basically nothing except for one odd thing. how can i eliminate it or reduce this idle load.

htop with K:

[image]

output of ps auxk-cputime | head:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     16124 50.1  0.0      0     0 ?        R    14:52  20:26 [irq/147-30be000]
root        34 10.2  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:43   5:03 [kworker/u8:2]
root     20389 13.7  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:07   3:29 [kworker/u8:3]
root     23144 11.8  0.0      0     0 ?        I    15:16   1:54 [kworker/u8:1]
root         1  0.3  0.1  25096  5876 ?        Ss   14:43   0:11 /sbin/init
```

cat /proc/interrupts

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
  1:          0          0          0          0     GICv3  25 Level     vgic
  3:     328565     337345     428599     353346     GICv3  30 Level     arch_timer
  4:          0          0          0          0     GICv3  27 Level     kvm guest timer
  6:         11         18         11         15  GPC-PSCI  47 Edge      iMX system counter timer
  7:          0          0          0          0     GICv3  23 Level     arm-pmu
  8:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 102 Edge      ddrc
  9:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 109 Edge      ddrc
 10:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 110 Edge      ddrc
 11:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 111 Edge      ddrc
 24:        940          0          1          0  irqsteer   3 Edge      dcss-dpr
 25:          0          0          0          0  irqsteer   4 Edge      dcss-dpr
 26:          0          0          0          0  irqsteer   5 Edge      dcss-dpr
 27:         12          0          0          0  irqsteer   6 Edge      dcss_ctxld
 28:        974          0          1          0  irqsteer   8 Edge      dcss_ctxld_kick
 29:        942          0          1          0  irqsteer   9 Edge      dcss_drm
 30:          0          0          0          0  irqsteer  16 Edge      dcss-dtrc
 31:          0          0          0          0  irqsteer  17 Edge      dcss-dtrc
 32:        127          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  34 Edge      nwl-dsi
 35:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  20 Edge      caam-snvs
 36:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI   4 Edge      30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey
 39:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  31 Edge      30820000.ecspi
 40:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  32 Edge      30830000.ecspi
 41:      23020          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  26 Edge      30860000.serial
 42:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  28 Edge      30880000.serial
 43:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  27 Edge      30890000.serial
 45:      46966          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  22 Edge      mmc0
 46:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  23 Edge      mmc1
 47:        449          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI   2 Edge      sdma
 48:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 103 Edge      sdma
 49:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 118 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
 50:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 119 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
 51:   27380157          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 120 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
 52:        314          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  35 Edge      30a20000.i2c
 53:     142955          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  36 Edge      30a30000.i2c
 54:         10          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  38 Edge      30a50000.i2c
 55:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  78 Edge      30280000.wdog
 56:        126          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 122 Edge      mx6-pcie-msi
 58:      60470          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  74 Edge      mx6-pcie-msi
 60:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  98 Edge      ddr_perf
 72:          0          0          0          0  gpio-mxc   9 Level     fsc_interrupt_int_n
107:          0          0          0          0  gpio-mxc  12 Edge      30b50000.usdhc cd
147:    2107008          0          0          0  gpio-mxc  20 Level     30be0000.ethernet-1:04
224:         30          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI  41 Edge      xhci-hcd:usb1
225:          2          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 105 Edge      30901000.jr0
226:         12          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 106 Edge      30902000.jr1
227:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 114 Edge      30903000.jr2
228:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI   0 Edge      PCIe PME, aerdrv
229:        126          0          0          0   PCI-MSI   1 Edge      eth1
261:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI   0 Edge      PCIe PME, aerdrv
262:      60470          0          0          0   PCI-MSI   1 Edge      eth2
IPI0:   3381139    7659801   19085661    7943330       Rescheduling interrupts
IPI1:       120        606        594        528       Function call interrupts
IPI2:         0          0          0          0       CPU stop interrupts
IPI3:         0          0          0          0       CPU stop (for crash dump) interrupts
IPI4:         0          4          6          5       Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI5:     13376      11413     245140      11958       IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:         0          0          0          0       CPU wake-up interrupts
Err:          0
```

cat /proc/interrupts | grep 30be000

```
root@imx6qpsabresd:/# cat /proc/interrupts | grep 30be000
 49:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 118 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
 50:          0          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 119 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
 51:   30549322          0          0          0  GPC-PSCI 120 Edge      30be0000.ethernet
147:    2350920          0          0          0  gpio-mxc  20 Level     30be0000.ethernet-1:04
```

Comment: Well, you've got some python applications running. No one knows what they are and what they do: it's up to you to figure it out.

Comment: they are basically doing nothing and the cpu usage shows that they barely take any resources.

Comment: well if this is sorted by CPU utilization, see if there are any disk wait operations

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `ps auxk-cputime | head`

Comment: I included the output of that command.

Comment: (1) [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). `htop` updates the screen, so this screenshot is somewhat justified; but `ps` gave you static text you can post as text. (2) Hint: to see more in `htop` press `K` (capital k, Shift+k). Press `?` to learn what it does.

Comment: cat /proc/interrupts and tell us what irq 147 is.

Comment: I have replaced htop with htop and K+shift as well as the outputs in code blocks and added the cat /proc/interrupts.

Comment: It is most likely something related to your Ethernet driver, based on what is posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have a so called interrupt storm. This is a usually a hardware bug. Please check whether Linux 5.19.1 fixes it, if not file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers -> Network

Could also be possible (though don't quote me on that) that your network card is in promiscuous mode, so your kernel is  listening to whatever junk traffic is on your LAN.

`sudo ethtool $interface` could show you more info.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore this interrupt, as its taking a lot of cpu usage for me.

Comment: Yes, if you add a different network card (ethernet, wifi, whatever) and `rmmod oldmodule`. Make sure you've updated your BIOS to the latest version - it might help.